# Compiling libcurl x86 on Linux x64

Tags: 64-bit, libcurl, cross-compiling

I've cross-compiled the bulk of my 32-bit code on my x64 Ubuntu install, but I can't work out how to do the same trick with libcurl.

I've tried many permutations of --host and/or --build i486, x86, etc. but none have helped. I've also tried editing the makefiles to include gcc's `-m32` flag manually, but it never shows up when I run them.

What should I be doing?

Comment: Instead of editing the Makefile, have you tried `CFLAGS=-m32 make`?

Comment: Yes, and it has no effect. Neither does `CC="gcc -m32"`.

Answer (score 4):

After you download and extract the libcurl source package, as a root user, run this command for setting up the build environment.

`configure --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu CFLAGS=-m32 CC=/usr/bin/gcc`

followed by

`make`

you can find the libs under `./lib/.libs/libcurl`.so from where you ran the make command.
if you dont find `/usr/bin/gcc`, you will have to install gcc for 32-bit cross compilation env in a 64-bit machine.

Comment: I know this a bit late, but I can do this and it works fine, except all the tests fail when running `make test`. Is there a way to run the tests for x86 on a x64 system?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave us an error message.  I've had issues on Ubuntu x64 systems compiling 32-bit code with 'ld' errors.. I solved it by adding LDEMULATION=elf_i386 to my environment.

Comment: There is no error message. The compile is successful - it just produces a 64bit binary. I've taken this to the curl mailing list, FYI (http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2010-09/0129.html).